# How to reverse engineer a new table in an existing Entity Framework project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I reverse engineered some tables from my database to use with Entity Framework. 
Now I would like to know how to do the following:

1. A table was added to the database. How do I reverse engineer that new table, and add it to my existing EF project?
2. One of the already referenced tables in EF has a new column. How do I update the EF classes and project to include this change, without creating a new project?

Comment: Are you using code first or database first?

Comment: I am using code first